# star patterns using while loops

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I'd like to make star patterns in this link

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpq63AaQe8nlrbBKskHUlz2fLu3U6-7KJbNqXgDDqLujjhJm8r

by while loops and do-while loops, but have some problems plz help

```
int i,j,k;
i = 5;
j = 1;
k = 5;

while (i > 0)
{   
    while (j < i)
    {
        printf(" ");
        j++;
    }
    while (k >= i)
    {
        printf("*");
        k--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i--;
}
```

why isn't it working? where should I fix?

Comment: move the initialisation of j and k into the big loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize `j` and `k` after `i--`

```
j=1;
k=5;
```

Like so:

```
int i,j,k;
i = 5;
j = 1;
k = 5;

while (i > 0)
{   
    while (j < i)
    {
        printf(" ");
        j++;
    }
    while (k >= i)
    {
        printf("*");
        k--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i--;
    j = 1;
    k = 5;
}
```

Tested this here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1-_m9Pj4

Comment: thank you so much!! can you help me make this to do-while loop? it's not working by just switching statements

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't work because you are not initialising the variables properly inside your while loop. I have made corrections and the following code works.

Make sure you set the values of j and k back to the initial values for each iteration

```
int main(){
int i,j,k;
i = 5;
j = 1;
k = 5;

while (i > 0)
{   
    while (j < i)
    {
        printf(" ");
        j++;
    }
    while (k >= i)
    {
        printf("*");
        k--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i--;
    j=1;
    k=5;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm down voting this not because the answer was wrong but because your solution has C++ code in it and this question is tagged specifically for C